# Definindo rota dos controllers em diretórios Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, htaccess, route

Tenho muito controladores no meu projeto, com isso divido os controladores em pastas, site na pasta site, admin na pasta admin (dentro de *controllers*).

Mas não consigo acessar os controladores sem precisar colocar a base da pasta dos mesmos na URL, exemplo:

Quero acessar assim: `http://localhost/gabriel/projeto/sobre`

Mas só consigo assim: `http://localhost/gabriel/projeto/site/sobre`

Arquivo 'routes' está assim:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site/index/site";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['admin'] = "admin/login";
```

Já tentei modificar o `htaccess` mas não obtive resultado.
Coloquei mais uma linha no arquivo 'routes':

```
$route['(:any)'] = "site/$1";
```

Mas colocando essa linha ela entra em conflito com a rota do Admin e acaba podendo receber só um parâmetro na URL.

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente fazer dessa forma, usando o `(.*)` como grupo de captura, obtendo toda a URL:

```
$route['admin/(.*)'] = "admin/$1";
$route['(.*)'] = "site/$1";
```

Comment: Muito obrigado resolveu meu problema.
Estava tentando apenas com o (:any), não com o *

Comment: @user3092202 Se esta resposta resolveu seu problema, voce pode marca-la como certa.